# Can't change page-title header for archive-product.php on Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress

Pretty simple - I am trying to change the page-title on the Product Archive page in Woocommerce from an h1 header to an h2 header. I tried editing the archive-product.php file that I added to a woocommerce directory in my theme file, swapping this:

```html
<h1 class="woocommerce-products-header__title page-title"><?php woocommerce_page_title(); ?></h1>
```

with this:

```html
<h2 class="woocommerce-products-header__title page-title"><?php woocommerce_page_title(); ?></h2>
```

But it isn't working! Any ideas?

Comment: That would do it, but if you have caching on you won't see the change. Clear your local and wp cache plugin.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried doing that and it is still showing up as an h1 header!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that I had the woocommerce.php in my theme file. So I was unable to override the woocommerce/archive-product.php template in my theme. Whooops!